# making changes to Button in its OnPaint event

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I write one component that extends a Button.

I customized my `OnPaint()` event. I've made some changes dynamically, and want to refresh my component with those new details.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to redraw the component? Call `Refresh` or `Invalidate`.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special is needed, your custom code will be used as soon as the button gets its first paint notification.  A possible mistake is the location of the base.OnPaint() call.  This will not work for example:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    // Wrong order:
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(3, 3, Width - 7, Height - 7));
    base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

The base.OnPaint() method draws the default appearance of the button, wiping out your customization.  You have to call base.OnPaint() *before* drawing your stuff:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {
    base.OnPaint(e);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(3, 3, Width - 7, Height - 7));
}
```